# Comunicacion entre diferentes webs mediante rest

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0, rest, mongodb

Tengo una duda , supongamos que tenga un dominio

```
www.example.com
```

y 2 subdominios

```
www.sub1.example.com
www.sub2.example.com
```

Aclaro que los 3 paginas usan mongo express y todo el stack de node.

Si quisiera comunicar y compartir información entre estas 3 paginas cada uno corriendo en su propio servidor ,¿Cual seria la forma de hacerlo mediante rest?

Por ejemplo www.example.com tienen su propia configuracion de usuarios categorias,etc,etc

supongamos el modelo usuario tenga la siguiente estructura

```
User={
name:{type:string,required:true},
lastName:{type:string,require:true}
....
....
sub1id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,required=true},
sub2id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,required=true}
...
}
```

Siendo sub1id y sub2id las cuentas del usuario en el subdominio1 y 2 , entonces supongamos que estoy en el subdominio 1 y quiero traer informacion del dominio principal por decir los 10 ultimos post del usuariox , entonces mando una consulta a la api con un token que contenga en ella el id del usuario y su sesion ,  luego valido en el dominio principal y devuelo el resultado correspondiente si ha pasado correctamente.

Lo mismo para subdominio1 a 2 o del subdominio2 a 1 ,etc,etc.

Quería saber si esta seria una forma aceptable en cuando a seguridad y escalabilidad o de que otra forma podría hacerse.

PD:Es obvio que tengo que usar https.

Comment: Los tres comparten el mismo storage o cada uno tiene su storage (o BBDD) por separado?

Comment: Pues estoy diseñando todavia esa parte ,estaba pensando que cada aplicacion tenga su propio storage , y en cada storage  en el modelo usuario solo hago referencia al id del otro usuario en el storage/aplicacion , sin embargo estoy en duda , o deberia manejarlo desde 1 mismo storage?

Comment: Si vas a usar tokens, entonces las tres tienen que leer de la misma tabla o colección de tokens. Y para generar el token, tienen que autenticarse contra la tabla de usuarios, que tb debiera ser común. Para el resto de las relaciones cada app puede tener sus propios datasources. Frameworks como loopbackjs permiten hacer joins entre datasources distintos.